# How to configure mongo config in kubernetes so my node application can access it

Tags: node.js, mongodb, kubernetes, config

This is my config file

```
  apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap  # This defines the type (should be "ConfigMap" for a config file)
metadata:
  name: mongo-config  # This is a user-defined name for the ConfigMap
data:
  MONGO_URI: mongo-service  # This entry specifies the service name used as an endpoint to access the MongoDB
  DATABASE: "e-commerce"
```

this is my secret file

```
    apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret  # For a secret file, the kind should be "Secret"
metadata:
  name: mongo-secret  # This is a user-defined name for the Secret
type: Opaque  # Default type for a secret file
data:
  mongo-user: bW9uZ291c2Vy  # The value here should be converted to base64
  mongo-password: bW9uZ29wYXNzd29yZA==  # The value here should be converted to base64
```

this is my pvc file

```
    apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mongo-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 80Mi  # Specify the size in Mebibytes (MB)
```

this is my mongo deployment and service file

```
    apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo-deployment
  labels:
    app: mongo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mongodb
          image: mongo:5.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          env:
            - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
              value: "admin"
            - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mongo-secret
                  key: mongo-password
            - name: MONGO_URI
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: mongo-config
                  key: MONGO_URI
            - name: DATABASE
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: mongo-config
                  key: DATABASE
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mongo-data
              mountPath: /data/db  # Adjust if needed
      volumes:
        - name: mongo-data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mongo-pvc  # Name of your PersistentVolumeClaim (PVC)

---

#here we describe service

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service    #it should be service
metadata:
  name: mongo-service   #it should be anything (remeber in config file we use this service name)
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongo          #it should match the name of the pods so service knows for which pods it should forward the request
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 27017        #it shuld be anything (better to make it same as container port)
      targetPort: 27017   #it should be the same as container port
```

this is my node deployment file

```
 apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment  # Deployment file kind should be "Deployment"
metadata:
  name: productmicroservice-deployment
  labels:
    app: productmicroservice
spec:
  replicas: 1  # How many pods you want to create
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: productmicroservice
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: productmicroservice
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: productmicroservice
        image: faizannaeem1994/productsmicroservice:latest  # Image name; using official mongo image with tag 7.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8002  
        env:
        - name: MONGO_URI  # Environment variables used in the code
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: mongo-config  # Secret file metadata name
              key: MONGO_URI  # Defined in secret file
        - name: DATABASE  # Environment variables used in the code
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: mongo-config  # Secret file metadata name
              key: DATABASE  # Defined in secret file
---
# Here we describe service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service  # It should be "Service"
metadata:
  name: productmicroservice-service  # It can be anything (remember in config file we use this service name)
spec:
  type: NodePort  # Make it an external service so we can access it
  selector:
    app: productmicroservice  # It should match the name of the pods so service knows for which pods it should forward the request
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8002  # It can be anything (better to make it the same as container port)
      targetPort: 8002  # It should be the same as the container port
      nodePort: 30100  # Range is from 30000 to 32767
```

When i do the deployment it shows me this error in logs of pod

```
mongo-service
MongoParseError: Invalid connection string
    at parseConnectionString (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/uri_parser.js:585:21)
    at connect (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/connect.js:283:3)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:284:5
    at maybePromise (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:692:3)
    at MongoClient.connect (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:280:10)
    at Object.connectToServer (/usr/src/app/db/conn.js:14:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/server.js:54:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
```

My Node application is using this in conn.js

```
    const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const connectionString = process.env.MONGO_URI;
console.log(connectionString)
const database = process.env.DATABASE;
const client = new MongoClient(connectionString, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

let dbConnection;

module.exports = {
  connectToServer: function (callback) {
    client.connect(function (err, db) {
      if (err || !db) {
        return callback(err);
      }

      dbConnection = db.db(database);
      console.log('Successfully connected to MongoDB.');

      return callback();
    });
  },

  getDb: function () {
    return dbConnection;
  },
};
```

What i am doing wrong ?
Note : I am just learning kubernetes and all of this stuff

Comment: It says "invalid connection string", so maybe show us your connection string `process.env.MONGO_URI`

Comment: it is taking from env variable in which there is a variable name only , nit its value . the variable name is MONGO_URI
i have configured it in my config maps of mongo service

Comment: do i need to pass the connection string in env variable ? is it possible to pass it from kubernetes?

Comment: In the ConfigMap, `MONGO_URI` just has the value `mongo-service`; it doesn't appear to actually be a URI.

Comment: @DavidMaze I found somewhere it should be the name of the service . can you correct me ?

Comment: I solved by giving the proper url mongodb://mongo-service:27017